# clang++, ld: Undefined Symbols while running V8 sample application in MacOS 14.3

Tags: macos, v8, clang++

I am trying to run sample V8 embedded application referred from here: [https://v8.dev/docs/embed][1] . (hello-world.cc)

I have build the v8 from source, and could locate all the libraries such as libv8_monolith, libv8_libbase, libv8_libplatform .

When I execute command

```
clang++ -I. -Iinclude samples/hello-world.cc -o hello_world -fno-rtti -lv8_monolith -lv8_libbase -lv8_libplatform -ldl -Lout.gn/x64.release.sample/obj/ -pthread -std=c++17 -DV8_COMPRESS_POINTERS -DV8_ENABLE_SANDBOX
```

I got below error while linking. it could not find the symbols.

```
ld: Undefined symbols:   v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform(int, v8::platform::IdleTaskSupport, v8::platform::InProcessStackDumping, std::__1::unique_ptr<v8::TracingController, std::__1::default_delete<v8::TracingController>>, v8::platform::PriorityMode), referenced from:
      _main in hello-world-c8e5eb.o   std::__Cr::__shared_weak_count::__get_deleter(std::type_info const&) const, referenced from:
      vtable for std::__Cr::__shared_ptr_pointer<v8::internal::BackingStore*, std::__Cr::default_delete<v8::internal::BackingStore>, std::__Cr::allocator<v8::internal::BackingStore>> in libv8_monolith.a[57](api.o) ...... ...... 

[More lines]

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

OS: macOS Sonoma 14.3

Comment: What's in the `args.gn` file of your V8 build? Certain details in the error message sound like you haven't used the build args that the documentation recommends.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I followed this document https://v8.dev/docs/build to build. And when I check args by running `gn args out/x64.release --list`, I could see the architecture is set properly. x64. Should I check some other variable ? or Is there any other document I need to follow ?

Comment: The architecture is not the issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, V8 links against its own bundled copy of `libc++`. That's what you get by following the convenience instructions at `v8.dev/docs/build`. Building V8 against libc++ requires you to link your embedding application against (a matching version of) libc++ as well, which is totally doable but might be inconvenient, especially if you have other dependencies and constraints.

To make embedding easier, follow the instructions at `v8.dev/docs/embed`, including the build instructions there. The `v8.gen.py` step listed there produces a build configuration that disables usage of the bundled libc++, linking against your system's C++ library instead (probably `libstdc++`, on most systems).
Of course, the listed steps just offer convenience, and you can also make the required changes yourself: run `gn args out/x64.release`, and in the editor that opens, add `use_custom_libcxx = false`. Save and quit (to cause regeneration of build files), then recompile V8. Then linking against it should Just Work™ (at least as far as the C++ standard library is concerned).

---

Side note: on SO or really anywhere, **when asking questions, it helps to be specific and precise**.

Post the *exact* command(s) you ran. Don't copy-paste a command line from one documented workflow when you've in fact been following a different workflow.
(In this case: the `-Lout.gn/x64.release.sample/obj/` part and the beginning of your question looks like you followed `v8.dev/docs/embed`, which should have given you the build config you need; but the error message and your later comment clarified that you actually followed `v8.dev/docs/build`, where that argument would have been `-Lout/x64.release/obj/`.)

When someone asks for the contents of your `args.gn` file, post the contents of that file, instead of running some perhaps-vaguely-related command and reporting on partial observations you made there. When someone volunteers to help you, give them what they ask for in order to be able to help you.

Ideally, post *complete* repro instructions, including any code that's required to reproduce your issue, and every single command that needs to be run. If it's more than you want to fit into the question, upload relevant files e.g. as a GitHub gist or project. Don't make people guess what you may have done or meant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the context about the libc++ thing in V8. Finally following v8.dev/docs/embed worked for me as you mentioned!. Also thanks for the constructive feedback on asking question forums. Will be more careful in the future. Thanks!